# C# regex string that is not another string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match an at least 3 letter word, preceded by any character from class [-_ :] any amount of times, that is not this specific 3 letter word string2.

Ex:
if string2="VER"

in

```
"    ODO VER7"
matched "    ODO"
```

or

```
"_::ATTPQ VER7"
matched "_::ATTPQ"
```

but if

```
" VER7"
```

it shoudn't match  " VER"

so I thought about

```
Regex.Match(inputString, @"[-_:]*[A-Z]{3,}[^(VER)]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

where

`[-_:]*` checks for any character in class, appearing 0 or more times

`[A-Z]` the range of letters that could form the word

`{3,}` the minimum amount of letters to form the word

`[^(VER)]` the grouping construct that shouldn't appear

I believe however that `[A-Z]{3,}` results in any letter at least 3 times (not what i want)
and `[^(VER)]` not sure what it's doing

Comment: Just filter out `VER` as a second step. `var m = Regex.Match(inputString, @"..."); if (m.Value != "VER") { … do something … }`. Trying to jam all this into a single regular expression will be far less readable.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^ *[-_:]*\b(?!VER)[A-Z]{3,} VER`  https://regex101.com/r/EyeNXP/1

Answer (score 2):

Using `[^(VER)]` means a negated character class where you would match any character except `(` `)` `V` `E` or `R`

For you example data, you could match 0+ spaces or tabs (or use `\s` to also match a newline).

Then use a negative lookahead before matching 3 or more times A-Z to assert what is on the right is not `VER`.

If that is the case, match 3 or more times A-Z followed by a space and VER itself.

```
^[ \t]*[-_:]*(?!VER)[A-Z]{3,} VER
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b+%5ct%5d*%5b-_%3a%5d*%28%3f!VER%29%5bA-Z%5d%7b3%2c%7d+VER&i=++++ODO+VER7%0d%0a%0d%0a_%3a%3aATTPQ+VER7%0d%0a%0d%0a+VER7&o=m)

Comment: Good explaining why [^(VER)] doesn't work, have a +

Comment: Great answer and explanation of why the user's regex wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

`^\s*[-_:]*(?!VER)[A-Z]{3,}`

This regex asserts that between the start and end of the string, there's zero or more of your characters, followed by at least 3 letters. It uses a negative lookahead to make sure that `VER` (or whatever you want) is not present.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ui7dPG/5)

Answer (score 1):

This would match the preceding class characters `[-_ :]` of 3 or more letters/numbers
that do not start with `VER` (as in the samples given) :

`[-_ :]+(?!VER)[^\W_]{3,}`

https://regex101.com/r/wLw23I/1